# Making NSTableView columns sortable via Interface Builder

Tags: swift4, nstableview, xcode9

I have an NSTableView that I'd like to make sortable using the Interface Builder method, and I'm having trouble with Apple's [Guides and Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/SortingTableViews/SortingTableViews.html) description of how to do it.  Based on comments to the original question I think this documentation is too far out of date and is pointing me in the wrong direction, so I'm rewriting my question.

Given the following additions to a default Cocoa application template:

```
class Foo: NSObject {

    @objc dynamic var name : String
    @objc dynamic var colour : String

    override init() {
        name = "name"
        colour = "colour"

        super.init()
    }

    init(_ name : String, _ colour : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour

        super.init()
    }
}
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @objc dynamic var fooList : [Foo] = [Foo("Bar", "Red"),
                                         Foo("Baz", "Green"),
                                         Foo("Beelzebub", "Blue")]

}
```

I've added an `NSArrayController` and `NSTableview` to the view controller in the `Main.storyboard`.  The Array Controller's "Controller Content" is bound to the view controller with the Model Key Path `self.fooList`, the Table View's "Table Content" is bound to the array controller with the default data (Controller Key of `arrangedObjects`), and each Table View Cell's "Value" is bound to the Table Cell View with a "Model Key Path" of `objectValue.name` and `objectValue.colour` respectively .  Up to this point everything works and I get data populating the Table View.

Based upon a suggestion in the comments, in order to make the list sortable I'm trying to add "Sort Descriptors" bindings. I've bound the Table View's "Sort Descriptors" to the Array Controller (default options) and the Array Controller's Sort Descriptors to the view controller (added "Model Key Path" of `self.fooList`).

At this point if I try to run the app I get an exception and traceback:

```
2018-04-15 17:45:13.354272-0400 ACTest[48227:16210514] -[ACTest.Foo key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000026c900
2018-04-15 17:45:13.356022-0400 ACTest[48227:16210514] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
2018-04-15 17:45:13.356042-0400 ACTest[48227:16210514] [General] -[ACTest.Foo key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000026c900
2018-04-15 17:45:13.356105-0400 ACTest[48227:16210514] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff57caffcb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff7e94dc76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff57d48a24 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff57c26610 ___forwarding___ + 1456
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff57c25fd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff5540eb48 -[NSArrayController automaticRearrangementKeyPaths] + 216
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff5540e95d -[NSArrayController _updateAutomaticRearrangementKeysPaths] + 30
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff555706ef -[NSArrayController _didChangeArrangementCriteriaWithOperationsMask:useBasis:] + 53
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff5557055e -[NSArrayController setSortDescriptors:] + 219
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff5570a6c4 -[NSControllerConfigurationBinder _updateSortDescriptors:] + 73
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff5570aa7b -[NSControllerConfigurationBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 279
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff55260cff -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 782
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff551dcbbd -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1430
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff552d813a -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 679
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff552d7d96 -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 136
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff55a2e180 -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:] + 236
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff551d0ecf NSApplicationMain + 729
    17  ACTest                              0x000000010000497d main + 13
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff7f53d115 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
2018-04-15 17:45:13.384522-0400 ACTest[48227:16210514] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ACTest.Foo key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000026c900'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff57caffcb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff7e94dc76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff57d48a24 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff57c26610 ___forwarding___ + 1456
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff57c25fd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff5540eb48 -[NSArrayController automaticRearrangementKeyPaths] + 216
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff5540e95d -[NSArrayController _updateAutomaticRearrangementKeysPaths] + 30
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff555706ef -[NSArrayController _didChangeArrangementCriteriaWithOperationsMask:useBasis:] + 53
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff5557055e -[NSArrayController setSortDescriptors:] + 219
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff5570a6c4 -[NSControllerConfigurationBinder _updateSortDescriptors:] + 73
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff5570aa7b -[NSControllerConfigurationBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 279
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff55260cff -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 782
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff551dcbbd -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1430
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff552d813a -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 679
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff552d7d96 -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 136
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff55a2e180 -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:] + 236
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff551d0ecf NSApplicationMain + 729
    17  ACTest                              0x000000010000497d main + 13
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff7f53d115 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

It's not clear to me where to go from here.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Bind Sort Descriptors of the table view to `sortDescriptors` of the array controller. Do you also want to sort the array in the ViewController?

Comment: Binding Sort Descriptors of the NSTableView to the array controller doesn't seem to be sufficient and results in an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error when the view loads.  It's not clear from your message how to direct that to `sortDescriptors` of the array controller.. Model Key Path doesn't do it (results in another error).

Comment: And no.. I don't need to sort the array from the ViewController.

Comment: Which selector is not recognized by which object/class? If you don't want to sort the array from the ViewController you don't need any code. The binding sets `sortDescriptors` of the array controller to `sortDescriptors` of the table view and the array controller will automagically sort the data. The sort key of the column is used to create a `NSSortDescriptor`, `name` is correct.

Comment: `2018-04-15 17:45:13.354272-0400 ACTest[48227:16210514] -[ACTest.Foo key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000026c900
` where the array controller is connected to `@objc dynamic var fooList : [Foo] = [...]` in the view controller class.

Comment: Looks like a "Sort Key" in the XIB is `key` and `Foo` doesn't have a KVO compliant property `key`.

Comment: By enabling and disabling it, I can see that the traceback is a result of binding the "Sort Descriptors" of the Array Controller to the View Controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a classic problem with Cocoa Bindings: when it works, it's like magic, but when it doesn't, you have no clue how to fix it. I assume you already get the table content populated so I won't touch on that. Here's how to handle the sorting:

#### For the table view:

Bind the table view's Sort Descriptors to the Array Controller's `sortDescriptors`:

[image: Bind table's Sort Descriptors]

#### For the table columns:

Set **Sort Key = name** for the Name column and **Sort Key = colour** for the Colour column. No additional bindings needed. You are all set!

[image: Set Sort Key]

Comment: Thanks!  That fixes the problem in both my test app and the real one I've been trying to figure this out for.  Any idea where this is actually documented?  I don't see how I would have found what to add to the "Controller Key" without your help.  Eventually I'm going to want to do similar things with the Selection Indexes for add/remove buttons and it would be good to know where to look.

Comment: I got this working from experience and a little trial and error. Frankly, I don't know if there's any documentation on it. You can try [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000167-BBCFBCAG)

Comment: Yeah, that's where I've been looking.  So far I haven't seen anything in that documentation that's been updated since 2014.  Lots of it dates back to 2012.  None of it applies to Swift or to recent Xcode updates.  Thanks though.